# Объединение меток [sass] и [scss], а также [css] и [css3]

Tags: предложение, метки

Допустим, на ruSo есть метки: [sass](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass), [scss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scss), на enSo за это отвечает одна метка - [`sass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass). Почему бы не объединить их также на ruSo.

Ещё на ruSo есть метки, такии как [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) и [css3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3), а на enSo только [`css`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css). Почему бы их тоже не объединить?

Comment: ЕМНИП, русский и английский СО по сути отдельные сайты, и какая-либо синхронизация между ними сильно ограничена.

Comment: Почитайте  пожалуйста другие предложения по объединениям меток и посмотрите что стоит добавить к вашему предложению (ссылки, статистику, аргументацию).